# Getting EKS Service IP Address from DNS using nslookup using commandline and grep

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, grep, amazon-eks, nslookup

I am having a question on how to retrieve the IP address of an EKS Service using the commandline using grep.

This is the nslookup command I used, and well it shows me the key Address: and the IPs but I only need one specific IP in that index and nothing else:

```
nslookup internal-a0cn71b0675e49.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com | grep Address
```

This gives me something like this:

```
Address: 10.178.0.8#53
Address: 10.107.206.89
Address: 10.107.205.124
```

I just need the middle IP part without the ***Address*** in front, how can I get one IP using grep on the commandline?

For example how can I get only:

> 10.107.206.89

using nslookup and grep in a linux commandline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
central-1.elb.amazonaws.com | awk '/Address/ { addr[cnt++]=$2 } END { print addr[2] }'
```

Search the output from nslookup for lines with "Address" using awk, create an array addr with the index incrementing and the value equal to the ip address. At the EnD, given we are only interested in the second address, print the second index of the addr array.

Comment: This prints me all three addresses, I only want the last one, how do I specify the index? e.g. something like: central-1.elb.amazonaws.com | awk '/Address/ { print $2 }[2]'

Comment: I've amended the answer

Comment: Sorry, but I noticed that I do not need the last but the middle value, how would that look like?

Comment: I've amended the answer. Assumes that there are only 3 addresses from nslookup.

Comment: Yes, there are only 3 addresses from nslookup. And this answer works for me thanks! Would you mind shortly explaining how this works? Does this addr[cnt++]=$2 create sort of a for loop with a counter? It looks very cryptic to me.

Comment: No worries. I've updated the explanation of the answer.

Comment: Thanks! The explanation makes it very clear, cheers!